# How to view user's webcam?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I was following phpacademy's video tutorials on how to stream your webcam using javascript. But now I would like to be able to view that webcams feed from another computer, such as creating a video chat. I've tried finding a tutorial or lesson online but can't come across anything yet. Anybody know how I would do this?

Comment: [WebRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC)

Answer (score 1):

"WebRTC" is what you are looking for. I highly recommend you to go through below mentioned links.

http://www.webrtc.org/

https://apprtc.appspot.com/

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment

You will get all the required information from above mentioned URLs.